# Syncfusion MAUI dataForm DataAnnotation attribute causing Java.LangIllegalArgument Exception

Tags: c#, maui, syncfusion, .net-8.0

I am using VS 2022, .NET 8.0, MAUI app with Syncfusion UI controls.

For a property of type integer in my model class, I added a data annotation with a `Prompt` attribute like this:

```
[Display(GroupName = "Other Info", Name = "Wages Rate if Fixed", Prompt = "Maximum 50k")]   // causing Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Layout:-90 < 0'
//[MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 5 Letters Allowed.")]   //max length doesn't work for Numeric type so..
//[DataType(DataType.Currency)]   //no implementation seen so..
public int WagesRate { get; set; }
```

The `Prompt` attribute value if commented, the error goes off and if re-added, the error starts throwing when I attempt to scroll the form